# Setting the $PORT variable on heroku

Tags: networking, heroku, tcp, port, config

On heroku, there is a variable named $PORT

This is randomly generated every time heroku starts an application.

Is there any way to set it so it will stay the same on startup?

NOTE: I tried heroku config:set and config:add but unless I'm doing it wrong, it hasn't taken effect.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the assigned port. If you bind to any other port than the assigned one, we will kill your process with an [R11 error code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r11-bad-bind)

Comment: The page you linked to no longer documents the R11 error code - does this mean that the policy has changed in the 4 years since you wrote this answer?